# Same application acting differently in win8 and win7

Tags: windows-8

I have an application which runs in lockdown mode with keys hooked that shows different behaviour in win8 and win7.In win7 when i induce alt+ctrl+del and select task manager,the window will come infront of my application.When i click on my application task manager disappears.But when i do the same on win8,the task manager is shown infront but the active state window is my application.Why this discrepancy in wind8?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 changed the default setting for "Always on top" in task manager.  To restore the Windows 7 mode of operation, check "Always on top" in the "Options" menu.

[image]

Comment: This happens when i checked always on the top on both win8 and7.my app  is set to be the topmost.